# MySQL data is not returned in PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, post

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");

$query = "Select 1 FROM dogs WHERE dog_id = :iddog ";

$query_params = array(':iddog'=> $_POST['iddogPHP2']);

$stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
$dono2 = $result ->fetchColumn(1);
$raca2 = $result ->fetchColumn(2); 
$sex2 = $result ->fetchColumn(3);
$estado2 = $result ->fetchColumn(4);

$query = "Select * FROM dogs WHERE dispon = 'Sim' AND dono != '$dono2' AND estado = '$estado2' AND raca = '$raca2' AND sex != '$sexo2' ";

try
{
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

?>
```

This is my code and the problem is that the variables `dono2`, `raca2`, `gender2` are not getting the values from the database. What's wrong in it?

Comment: print query result and check

Comment: From: Can not print I am working on android with a Communication THAT php

Comment: use `postman(Google chrome extension)` to make a `Rest API` call for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `SELECT 1` you need to use `SELECT *` in your first query.

```
$query = "Select * FROM dogs WHERE dog_id = :iddog ";
```

The following returns an array of results

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

So you would need to specify which one to reference.

```
$dono2 = $rows[0]['dono'];
$raca2 = $rows[0]['raca']; 
$sexo2 = $rows[0]['sex'];
$estado2 = $rows[0]['estado'];
```

Comment: Or change `fetchAll` to `fetch`. Looks nicer than adding the `0` index everywhere.

Comment: And rather than doing `SELECT *` get the columns you actually need

Comment: WORKS, really save my life haha

Answer (score 0):

```
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

fetch all rows from database you need to specify which row you want if it's multiple row

```
                $dono2 = $rows[0]['dono'];
                $raca2 = $rows[0]['raca']; 
                $sexo2 = $rows[0]['sex'];
                $estado2 = $rows[0]['estado'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bindParam(':iddog', $_POST['iddogPHP2']);
 $stmt->execute($query_params);

 $dono2 = $stmt ->fetchColumn(1);
 $raca2 = $stmt ->fetchColumn(2); 
 $sex2 = $stmt ->fetchColumn(3); 
 $estado2 = $stmt ->fetchColumn(4);
```